# Convert mp3 -> Video with static image ( ffmpeg/libav & BASH )

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

Some years ago I used the following bash script to get a video out of mp3's and one image (so the image in the video was freezed over the length of the mp3), which worked out fine.

```
i=0;
for file in *.mp3; 
do 
i=$((i+1));
ffmpeg -loop 1 -shortest -y -i image.jpg -i $file -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 $file.flv;
done
```

Now I wanted to use this again for doing the same.

**Problem:**

It **does not stop converting** at the end of the mp3. Means the current mp3 file eg. has a length of 3 minutes and the script converts until forever or I stop it, so the length of the flv is much bigger than 3 minutes.

(ffmpeg is installed, but with libav the same happens)

**Output:**

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.6-7:1.2.6-1~trusty1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 18:52:58 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:1.2.6-1~trusty1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    53.  5.103 / 53.  5.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[image2 @ 0x6d0740] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000 microseconds
Input #0, image2, from 'Bild2.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba, 382x417, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[mp3 @ 0x6c4ac0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510 microseconds
[mp3 @ 0x6c4ac0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'sons.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:35.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 127 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x6da700] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x6da700] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 2.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x6da700] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'sons.mp3.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv444p, 382x417, q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> libx264)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 108, accepted):

First of all, I would highly recommend you to [update ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) to a newer version. You are currently using v1.2.6-7, but as we speak, the current version is 2.3.3.

Here is a working command (see [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow)):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -shortest out.mp4
```

Also, you could optimize overall weight by reencoding audio if you're using raw sound (aiff or wave) as input:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -c:a aac -ab 112k -c:v libx264 -shortest -strict -2 out.mp4
```

For further reading, see this [related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887311/ffmpeg-1-image-1-audio-file-1-video).

Comment: Thanks mrgnou.
Version 1.2 is what you get by installing through the ppa mentioned on ffmpeg.org (https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg).

Comment: @gnou The mp4 does not work on iphone... please help

Comment: @neoDev You need to encode the audio channel in aac in that case, so use aac audio codec or libfdk_aac for a better quality (if your ffmpeg is compiled with it).

Comment: Works well, but very slow (about real time for a still image). Why?

Comment: In the end I get a 400 MB file from a 30 min mp3 (20 MB) and a still image.

Comment: Pro-Tip. The smaller the image you use as your "Image" file, the faster the conversion will be. I am using a 1px by 1px white image and getting 700x speedup. Also, filesize is very similar. For example, a 37mb m4a becomes a 38.5mb mp4. However, if you are doing this for YouTube, they do not like a 1px white image lol. So I opted for a 640x400 minimalist wallpaper (10KB) and am getting 60x. Good enough for now.

Comment: On Ubuntu 21.04 the solution still works. Thank you Leo!

Comment: @gnou I use wav instead of mp3 with second code

Answer (score 4):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a copy result.mkv
```

works with version 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I have used this:

```sh
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loop 1 -i img.png -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune stillimage -c:a copy -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mkv
```

- https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg/1041818#1041818
- https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-convert-an-audio-into-a-video/answer/Denny-Lenselink